# Spelling error in Malaysian eVisa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, malaysia, e-visas

We are planning a family trip to Malaysia next month. I applied for my wife's visa online and was granted it within 24 hours. Her name in her passport is Usna, but the visa has an added H: Husna. Will this pose a problem at Malaysian security or immigration? The visa is not printed on her passport.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely she's not getting on the plane, as the airline faces massive fines if transporting her without valid paperwork. And an entry permit with a misspelt name compared to the passport is **invalid**, full stop! Thus, even if she does make her way to Malaysian immigration, she's likely to be sent back

So her only solution is to apply for a new one.

Source: the [Malaysian eVisa website](https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/faq.jsp?lang=en)

> Q: Upon receiving my issued eVISA, I have realised that some of the information that I provided was wrong and needs corrections. What should I do?
>
> A: You must re-apply for a new eVISA with the correct information as per your travel documents.

Comment: Are you that sure? I've traveled with misspellings on entry permits and not once denied boarding.

Comment: @SheikPaul Hence "most likely" as check-in staff is supposed to enforce the country's rules. I've seen people being turned away simply for putting the surname and first name in the wrong order but spelling it all correctly